# Disabling password auto generation in password UITextField Swift

Tags: ios, swift, passwords, uitextfield

I have[ a reusable view that contains 3 UITextFields, and two of them are initially used for passwords. My problem is once I've used the UITextFields for password input, I can't seem to remove the "strong password" label and yellow background from the field, without assigning it as a first responder, or physically taping the field. Is there any way to turn this feature off in app, or make the Field reusable?

[email, and password image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IFhI.png)
[fields reused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfg7E.png)

Comment: Do you care to share some code please ?

Comment: It might be simpler to not reuse the fields; creating 2-3 new `UITextField`s is not a particularly heavy operation, and it would help avoid accidentally exposing the passwords.